# Чем является оборот с КАК в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, как

Чем в предложении является сравнительный оборот с *как*, когда он тесно связан со сказуемым, имеет значение приравнивания, отождествления?

*Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей.*

*Марья Ильинична сидела как на иголках.*

*Он говорил о привычных вещах как о чём-то необычайно интересном.* (Пауст.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, можно расценить по-разному, учитывая степень связанности со сказуемым.

*Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей.*- Обстоятельство: любил (как?), считая собственностью.

*Марья Ильинична сидела как на иголках*.- Сидела как на иголках-фразеологизм (беспокоилась) Можно счесть всё сказуемым, а можно только "как на иголках"(сидела беспокойно), тогда это будет обстоятельство. Это факультативный случай.

*Он говорил о привычных вещах как о чём-то необычайно интересном.* говорил как?- обстоятельство.

Comment: _Можно счесть всё сказуемым, а можно только "как на иголках"_ === ??? По-моему, что-то не то...

Comment: Явно тут описка. Можно считать "сидела"  сказуемым, а "как на иголках" – обстоятельством.

Comment: Конечно, описка. Просто, на мой взгляд, её нужно сначала устранить, а уж потом голосовать за ответ. А то получается как-то... не могу подобрать слово... _путано_, что ли.

Comment: Дело в том, что у Михельсона, например, "сидеть  как на иголках" - всё выражение названо идиомой, а идиома разбирается как один член предложения, в других, более современных, словарях идиома только "на иголках", мне тоже это более близко, действие-то всё-таки "сидела", а как?- как на иголках, т.е. беспокойно.